# How to create a dropdown menu using react js is this is a right to set a value after this how to approach this

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

```
const [selectedDepartment, setSelectedDepartment] = useState("");

  const DepartmentDropdown = () => {
    const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
      setSelectedDepartment(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(email);
    };
      return(
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="departments">Select a Department:</label>
            <select
              id="departments"
              value={selectedDepartment}
              onChange={handleSelectChange}
            >
              <option value="">--Select a Department--</option>
              <option value="ai&ds">AI&DS</option>
              <option value="cse">CSE</option>
              <option value="ece">ECE</option>
              <option value="eee">EEE</option>
              <option value="it">IT</option>
              <option value="mech">MECH</option>
            </select>
            {selectedDepartment && <p>You selected: {selectedDepartment}</p>}
          </div>)

}
```

Here, I have a doubt where would I use call  the function DepartmentDropdown. How to access this dropdown menu. Is there any other easiest way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't create the state inside your `DepartmentDropdown` component but make it in the parent component from which you will call `DepartmentDropdown`

```js
const DepartmentDropdown = ({handleSelectChange,selectedDepartment}) => {

    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="departments">Select a Department:</label>
        <select
          id="departments"
          value={selectedDepartment}
          onChange={(event) => {
            handleSelectChange(event.target.value)
         }}
        >
          <option value="">--Select a Department--</option>
          <option value="ai&ds">AI&DS</option>
          <option value="cse">CSE</option>
          <option value="ece">ECE</option>
          <option value="eee">EEE</option>
          <option value="it">IT</option>
          <option value="mech">MECH</option>
        </select>
        {selectedDepartment && <p>You selected: {selectedDepartment}</p>}
      </div>
    );
 
};
```

as it is shown in the code

```js
DepartmentDropdown = ({handleSelectChange,selectedDepartment}) =>
```

`handleSelectChange` and `selectedDepartment` will be passed as props to the `DepartmentDropdown` component

Now in your parent component you create `selectedDepartment` then pass it to `DepartmentDropdown` to make it able to show it 
and create `handleSelectChange` then pass it to `DepartmentDropdown` to make it able to update `selectedDepartment` state in the parent component:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  
    const [selectedDepartment, setSelectedDepartment] = useState("");
    const handleSelectChange = (value) => {
        setSelectedDepartment(value);
      };
     //...
      return (
        <>
         //... 
        <DepartmentDropdown handleSelectChange={handleSelectChange} selectedDepartment={selectedDepartment} />
         //... 
        </>
      )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With React function components, you use the name of the function as the component name in JSX, like this:

```js
<DepartmentDropdown />
```

It looks weird because it's a function being used as an element name, but that's how JSX works.